# php url parameters check

Tags: php, validation, url

I'm creating a website that relies on $_GET to function correctly.
It works like this: http://www.example.com/show?q=14&i=48 `q` and `i`  are IDs on MySQL server that must be fetched using mysql_query() and the like. Parameters are always integers.

If someones type the url without any parameters both PHP and MySQL yells errors. PHP for undefined variable(s) and MySQL for incorrect syntax.

What i've tried so far doesn't works i always get "Error";

```
if (is_int($_GET['q']) AND is_int($_GET['i']))
{
 echo "All good.";
}
else
{
 echo "Error.";
}
```

What am i doing wrong here.

Thanks,
atno

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're checking the **type** of the variable and not its content. Anything coming from a query string via `$_GET` is considered a string, so you should use [`ctype_digit()`](http://php.net/ctype_digit) instead if `is_int()`, and also checking if the values are present with [`empty()`](http://php.net/empty).

Comment: +1, my thoughts exactly. `ctype_digit()` or even doing `$_GET['i'] = (int)$_GET['i'];`

Comment: Casting also works, but I'd rather reject bad input than fix it

Answer (score 2):

You should use **`is_numeric`** instead of `is_int`.
`is_int` returns `false` for numeric strings.

Downside is that the `is_numeric` function also returns true for numbers like `"1.5"`.
If you don't want that, you can check the function [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php#95658)

Answer (score 0):

You should try the isset($_GET[q])

```
if(isset($_GET[q]) && isset($_GET[i])){

}
```

Comment: isset() isn't the right function to solve it because as kemp said everything in $_GET considered a string. So http://www.example.com/show?q=&i= returns "All good."

Comment: According to the question, the case on your example does not happen. He says, "If someones type the url without any parameters both PHP and MySQL yells errors." In your example there exist two parameters. My partial solution only helps on the PHP side, but not on the MySQL side.